# Finding a Fixed Point Solution

Tags: numerical-methods, numerical-optimization

I'm trying to solve the following where $A,B >0$ in the most general case (don't assume they are equal).  Wolfram Alpha cannot compute this in the allowed time, but I feel some fixed point algorithm should work.  I'm not too familiar with numerics, could someone find a solution via Matlab etc...

$$\frac{1}{\pi}\arctan\left(\frac{(B-A)}{(\sqrt{x}+\frac{(A*B)}{\sqrt{x}})}\right)=\sqrt{x}$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not surprised that WolframAlpha cannot solve the equation directly.  It's a difficult equation that Mathematica's `Reduce` command can't deal with.  However, it's easy to solve given specific values of $A$ and $B$.  In wolfram alpha, you can just type the input directly with specific values of $A$ and $B$ to solve or plot.  For example, here's how to [find the solution for $A=0.2$ and $B=1$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve%20ArcTan%5B%281-0.2%29/%281*0.2/Sqrt%5Bx%5D%20%2b%20Sqrt%5Bx%5D%29%5D/Pi%20==%20Sqrt%5Bx%5D):

[image]

If you have Mathematica, you can define a function of $A$ and $B$ that returns the solution and then visualize the function via a plot or contour plot.  Here are the results:

[image]

The function definition is

```
f[A_?NumericQ, B_?NumericQ] := x /. FindRoot[
  ArcTan[(B - A)/((A*B)/Sqrt[x] + Sqrt[x])]/Pi == Sqrt[x],
  {x, 0.1, 0.0, 0.2}]
```